# Fix position of an element only inside div

Tags: html, css

I have the bellow code -- I am trying to make "hey!" fixed only inside the white container. I tried using `margin-left:0;margin-top:0` in `position:fixed`, `z-index` to hide it from the red and black container but it didn't work.

```html
<div style="height:1000px;background:red;">
</div>
<div style="height:400px;">
  <div style="position:fixed;border:thin solid blue;top:0;left:0;">
    hey!
  </div>
</div>
<div style="height:1000px;background:black;">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What do you tryin' to archive? Do you want that the "hey" scroll only inside of the white thing?

Comment: fixed position makes the element stay relative to the whole document...not to a specific container . you either use javascript for this either you rethink the solution ( depending on what actually you want to achieve )

Answer (score 0):

fixed position makes the element stay relative to the whole document...not to a specific container . you either use javascript for this either you rethink the solution ( depending on what actually you want to achieve )

if you really want to use position fixed, and your `red` div will always be at the very top of the document, you could use something like this

`hey` will always be there ( even outside the red div and inside the black div ) but it will be hidden with z-index . you also need to set a `position` on the black div so the `z-index` to have any effect

```css
body {
margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:1000px;background:red;z-index:0;position:relative">
</div>
<div style="height:400px;">

    <div style="position:fixed;border:thin solid blue;top:0;left:0;z-index:1;">
hey!
    </div>
</div>
<div style="height:1000px;background:black;position:relative;z-index:2;">
</div>
```